# Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method AWT Program

Tags: java, user-interface, compiler-errors, awt, abstract-class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class QuadraticSolver extends Frame implements ActionListener, WindowListener
{
private TextField tfX2;
private TextField tfX;
private TextField tfNum;
private TextField tfVal1;
private TextField tfVal2;
private TextField tfRoots;

private Label lblX2;
private Label lblX;
private Label lblNum;
private Label lblVal1;
private Label lblVal2;
private Label lblRoots;

private Button btnCheckRoots;
private Button btnCalc;
private Button btnClear;

double a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
double Val1 = 0, Val2 = 0, Discriminant = 0;
String StrVal1, StrVal2;

public QuadraticSolver()
{
    Panel panelX2Comp = new Panel(new FlowLayout());
    {
        lblX2 = new Label("Enter Co-Efficient Of X^2:");
        panelX2Comp.add (lblX2);

        tfX2 = new TextField("", 20);
        tfX2.setEditable(true);
        panelX2Comp.add(tfX2);
    }

    Panel panelXComp = new Panel(new FlowLayout());
    {
        lblX = new Label("Enter Co-Efficient Of X:");
        panelXComp.add(lblX);

        tfX = new TextField("", 20);
        tfX.setEditable(true);
        panelXComp.add(tfX);
    }

    Panel panelNumComp = new Panel(new FlowLayout());
    {
        lblNum = new Label("Enter Number:");
        panelNumComp.add(lblNum);

        tfNum = new TextField("", 20);
        tfNum.setEditable(true);
        panelNumComp.add(tfNum);
    }

    Panel panelButtons = new Panel(new FlowLayout());
    {
        btnCalc = new Button("Calculate");
        btnCalc.setEnabled(false);
        panelButtons.add(btnCalc);
        {
            btnCalc.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                 @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    a = Double.parseDouble(tfX2.getText());
                    b = Double.parseDouble(tfX.getText());
                    c = Double.parseDouble(tfNum.getText());

                    Val1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(Discriminant)) / (2 * a);
                    Val2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(Discriminant)) / (2 * a);

                    StrVal1 = String.valueOf(Val1);
                    StrVal2 = String.valueOf(Val2);

                    tfVal1.setText(StrVal1);
                    tfVal2.setText(StrVal2);

                    tfX2.setText("");
                    tfX.setText("");
                    tfNum.setText("");

                    btnCalc.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
            );
        }

        btnCheckRoots = new Button("Nature Of Roots");
        panelButtons.add(btnCheckRoots);
        {
            btnCheckRoots.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                 @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    a = Double.parseDouble(tfX2.getText());
                    b = Double.parseDouble(tfX.getText());
                    c = Double.parseDouble(tfNum.getText());

                    Discriminant = (b*b) - (4*(a*c));

                    if (Discriminant == 0)
                    {
                        tfRoots.setText("Equal");
                        btnCalc.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                    else if (Discriminant < 0)
                    {
                        tfRoots.setText("Imaginary");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tfRoots.setText("Real, Distinct");
                        btnCalc.setEnabled(true);
                    }


                }

            }
            );
        }

        btnClear = new Button("Clear");
        panelButtons.add(btnClear);
        {
            btnClear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
            {

                 @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    a = 0; b = 0; c = 0;
                    Val1 = 0; Val2 = 0; Discriminant = 0;


                    tfX2.setText("");
                    tfX.setText("");
                    tfNum.setText("");
                    tfVal1.setText("");
                    tfVal2.setText("");
                    tfRoots.setText("");
                }
            }
            );
        }


    }   

    Panel panelRoots = new Panel(new FlowLayout());
    {
        lblRoots = new Label ("Nature Of Roots:");
        panelRoots.add(lblRoots);

        tfRoots = new TextField("", 20);
        tfRoots.setEditable(false);
        panelRoots.add(tfRoots);
    }

    Panel panelValues = new Panel(new FlowLayout());
    {
        lblVal1 = new Label("First Value:");
        panelValues.add(lblVal1);

        tfVal1 = new TextField("", 10);
        tfVal1.setEditable(false);
        panelValues.add(tfVal1);

        lblVal2 = new Label("Second Value:");
        panelValues.add(lblVal2);

        tfVal2 = new TextField("", 10);
        tfVal2.setEditable(false);
        panelValues.add(tfVal2);

    }

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());  // "this" Frame sets to BorderLayout
    add(panelX2Comp);
    add(panelXComp);
    add(panelNumComp);
    add(panelButtons);
    add(panelRoots);
    add(panelValues);

    setTitle("Matrix Multiplier"); // "this" Frame sets title
    setSize(400, 200);        // "this" Frame sets initial size
    setVisible(true);    


    addWindowListener(this);
}

 @Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
{
    System.exit(0);  // Terminate the program
}
 @Override
 public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) { }
 @Override
 public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) { }
 @Override
 public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) { }
 @Override
 public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) { }
 @Override
 public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) { }
 @Override
 public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) { }


public static void main(String args[])
{
    new QuadraticSolver();
}
}
```

So this is my code. it give me an error saying "QuadraticSolver.java:4: error: `QuadraticSolver` is not `abstract` and does not override abstract method `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` in `ActionListener`
`public class QuadraticSolver extends Frame implements ActionListener, WindowListener`"

I have no idea what to do. I tried adding @Override before all ActionListener events, Still doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to make the class implement ActionListener?

Comment: Umm... yeah. Exactly as the error message states. `QuadraticSolver` does not implement `actionPerformed`.

Comment: Uhh....I was copy-pasting snippets of code from a guide I found online. This is my 3rd awt program so far. Dunno much about it yet

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured. Well since you're not too far along, I'd suggest you get into Swing instead of going any further with AWT (which is pretty much obsolete). You should take some time to run through the [Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). Swing it built on top of AWT, so it's not that far off from what you've already picked up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `QuadraticSolver` implements `ActionListener`, it should implement `actionPerformed`.

You implemented that method in an anonymous class.

To solve it, either add an implementation of  `actionPerformed` to `QuadraticSolver` or don't require `QuadraticSolver` to implement that interface.

Comment: I deleted the ActionListener line from the class declaration and now the program runs. Thank You So Much!

Comment: I still didn't get what the problem was with that line being there. Would someone be kind enough to explain please?

Comment: @user287872 When a non abstract class implement an interface, it must implement all methods declared in that interface (and any interfaces that this interface inherits from). Since you declared your class to implement ActionListener, you were required to implement the methods of that interface in your class. You were missing an implementation of actionPerformed in that class.

Comment: Still a little high level for me, but i got the gist. Thanks Eran for your quick reply. :D

Answer (score 0):

I Noticed that you implement actionperformed for your actionlistener of your button.When you declare that you are going to implement an interface, you need a separate actionperformed method in your class.
like

```
public class QuadraticSolver implements ActionListener{
@Override 
public void  actionPerformed(ActionEvent){}
}
```

Comment: Uhh. I don't understand any of that. Still not through with all that terminology. Just started AWT programming yesterday. But yeah, I followed the other answer and now the program works. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

As you have used ActionListener so you are bound to override its method which is
actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) otherwise it will give this error.